# mvn validate throws Dependency convergence error but mvn dependency:tree does not show the dependency

Tags: java, maven-3

mvn validate fails throwing dependency error.

```
Dependency convergence error for com.company.concepts:patients:2.4.14-SNAPSHOT paths to dependency are:
+-com.company.ion.concepts.patientlist:patient-list:1.4-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.company.concepts:patientlists:2.3.15-SNAPSHOT
    +-com.company.concepts:patients:2.4.14-SNAPSHOT
and
+-com.company.ion.concepts.patientlist:patient-list:1.4-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.company.concepts:patientlists:2.3.15-SNAPSHOT
    +-com.company.concepts:patients:2.4.14-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.company.concepts:patients:2.4.4-Alpha-5
```

Then I have run mvn dependency:tree to see if anywhere I am using 2.4.4-Aplha-5 but did not find it anywhere.

```
[INFO] +- com.company.concepts:patientlists:jar:2.3.15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.company.concepts:patients:jar:2.4.14-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.company.xyz.common:xyz-common-demographic-proteus:jar:3.1:compile
```

I have tried every possible thing out there, but could not come to a solution.

I am using

> maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce
>
> Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>
> Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5

Comment: It looks like it's trying to resolve a previous version of itself..? That's pretty weird, maybe the dependency pom has some issues

Answer (score 1):

Try with this instead. It should show the different paths to that dependency in your project:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose=true
```